# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$file_id Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stdclass

I'm using woocommerce 3.8.1 with the last version of wordpress,
and I'm getting this error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$file_id in /../../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/helper/class-wc-helper.php on line 1159
```

and I have no idea about how to fix it,

Comment: Can you please list more details, is there any code for Woocommerce in your theme, if yes, can you please list it here?

Comment: I'm using Groci template,
there's multiple woocommerce codes in the template

Comment: When I disable "WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers Pro" the error disappear